# Promoting and demoting headers in orgstruct mode

Tags: org-mode, header-line

It looks as if the promotion and demotion of headers using <kbd>M-Right</kbd>, <kbd>M-S-Right</kbd>, <kbd>M-Left</kbd>, <kbd>M-S-Left</kbd> is disabled in `orgstruct-mode` as per [this emacs-orgmode GNU thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-03/msg00560.html).

Also, making direct function calls like <kbd>M-x</kbd>`orgstruct-hijacker-org-metaright` do nothing.

Does anyone have a patch that enables that?

Also, I can't have `orgstruct-heading-prefix-regexp` as `nil`; **I need to set it at least to the comment characters of the major mode in which I am using orgstruct.** And I am not planning on using block commenting for each orgstruct heading.

In my case I am setting this var to `//;`.

I am also curious... why would anyone not use the org mode directly if they are able to use orgstruct with this variable set to `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

A little later in that [same thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-03/msg00740.html), its a bit confusing but there is a commit that solves this.

```
 03b1edf org.el: Disable {pro,de}motion commands in orgstruct-mode if 
orgstruct-heading-prefix-regexp is non-nil
```

Which isn't entirely true. Setting `orgstruct-heading-prefix-regexp` to nil did not enable Pro/Demotion but setting it to an empty string did.

**Summary:**

Evalute the following in a buffer to allow promotion/demotion of headers in an orgstruct-mode buffer.

```
(setq orgstruct-heading-prefix-regexp "")
```

- I have confirmed this on emacs-24.4 with the latest org-mode from melpa

Comment: I forgot to mention.. I can't have `orgstruct-heading-prefix-regexp` as `nil`; **I need to set it atleast to the comment characters of the major mode in which I am using orgstruct.** And I am not planning on using block commenting for each orgstruct heading. In my case I am setting this var to `//; `. I am curious... Not questioning you specifically, but why would anyone not use the org mode directly if they are able to use orgstruct with this variable set to `nil`?

Comment: ahh.. I assumed you were using orgstruct-mode for text-mode or message-mode. For editing code I use org-babel-tangle. I havent used orgstruct for anything other than message-mode.

Comment: I just started using `outshine` today. It has many more features except that currently it can't hide `:archive:` tagged subtrees.